# touchend event properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, mobile-safari, touch-event

If I catch all touchend events from mobile devices with:

```
$(document.body).bind('touchend', function (e) {
var touch = e.touches[0]; // doesnt work
...
```

I need to get the touch.screenX, touch.screenY, touch.clientX and touch.clientX from the e paramter. All the examples I've seen suggest that e.touches will be a collection, and you can get at the touch details with `e.touches[0]`. In my tests on an ipad, `e.touches` is always undefined. I'm not using any jquery plugins.

Also tried e.targetTouches, which is also undefined.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Actually, released touches will be found in the changedTouches array, ie:

`e.changedTouches[0].pageX // get the end x page coordinate for a released touch`

I think this is slightly more reliable than going through the originalEvent property.

You can read more on changedTouches here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#changedtouches-of-a-touchevent

Comment: I agree, this is the correct solution. I, myself, am using this since it has the correct data needded and why mix up more APIs than needed.

Comment: This is not the case with android if you are using jQuery. $('#test').on('touchend', function (evt) { console.log(evt.changedTouches); }); is empty, same if you do $('#test').bind('touchend'... but if you cut jquery out of the equation and do getElementBy and addEventListener it works..

Comment: @WORMSS: The answer is unclear with regard to the jQuery event.originalEvent property. That issue is addressed specifically here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999724/touchstart-in-javascript-no-longer-returns-touchlist

Comment: e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX is the correct answer!
[EDITED 20-11-2017]

Comment: This ended my weeks of struggle. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

The touches property is an TouchList object. You can see the TouchList class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchListClassReference/TouchList/TouchList.html).

If you monitor its length property with this example code on #log div:

```
$('#element').bind('touchstart', function(event) 
{
    $('#log').append(event.originalEvent.touches.length+'<br/>');
});

$('#element').bind('touchmove', function(event) 
{
    $('#log').append(event.originalEvent.touches.length+'<br/>');
});

$('#element').bind('touchend', function(event) 
{
    $('#log').append(event.originalEvent.touches.length+'<br/>');
});
```

you will obtain 1 while executing touchstart and touchmove, an 0 when executing touchend. That is why you obtain undefined from `e.touches[0]`.