# touchstart in JavaScript no longer returns TouchList

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I ran into a very strange problem. I am binding the `touchstart` event to an element, and would like to retrieve the X and Y co-ordinates of the event. All [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) online indicates that this is available through one of the following:

- `e.touches`
- `e.targetTouches`
- `e.changedTouches`

However, the following code, called on `#test` returns `undefined` for all three supposed arrays when running this from jQuery:

```
$('#test').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    alert(e.targetTouches);
    alert(e.touches);
    alert(e.changedTouches);
});
```

You can see a demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/c7UKV/1/ (you need to view it on a mobile device, or you can go straight to the results here > http://jsfiddle.net/c7UKV/1/embedded/result/).

My question is does anyone know of a work around, or is jQuery normalizing the event in some way that I'm not aware of? The issue exists across all versions of jQuery I tested (1.6+) and also on the iOS Simulator and on physical iDevices.

As an update to the above, calling this using vanilla JavaScript (rather than jQuery) returns the correct result. For example the following code works without a problem:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('touchstart', checkCoords, false);

function checkCoords(e)
{
    alert(e.targetTouches);
    alert(e.touches);
    alert(e.changedTouches);
}
```

So it would appear that this is a jQuery issue, rather than anything else. You can see the above working correctly in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c7UKV/8/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), not every property of the original `event` is copied to jQuery's normalized event object.

You can still access it using originalEvent object:

```
$('#test').bind('touchstart', checkCoords );

function checkCoords(e){
  alert(e.originalEvent.targetTouches);
  alert(e.originalEvent.touches);
  alert(e.originalEvent.changedTouches);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed the documentation about that.